# Obtain first timestamp over a window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table with a `person_id`, `timestamp` and `name`. I'm Trying to write a query to obtain the first timestamp for a person on a given date (in a given timezone). Naturally, I tried using FIRST_VALUE and partitioning over the day, but not sure why it's not working.

```
SELECT first_value("timestamp") OVER w,
  date_trunc('day', "timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central')
FROM analytics_analyticsevent as ae
WHERE person_id=3
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', "timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central')
WINDOW w as (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', "timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central'))
```

Which gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  column "ae.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2: SELECT first_value("timestamp") OVER w,
                           ^
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You must add first_value("timestamp")  in group by

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a classic `top-n-per-group`. Usually people use `ROW_NUMBER`, like this:

```
SELECT
    "timestamp"
    ,dt
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            "timestamp"
            ,date_trunc('day', "timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central') AS dt
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', "timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central') 
                ORDER BY "timestamp") AS rn
        FROM analytics_analyticsevent as ae
        WHERE person_id=3
    ) AS T
WHERE
    T.rn = 1;
```